# Strange error with realloc in VS 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, realloc

I have a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct NOTE
{
    char NAME[50],  
         TELE[30];  
    int  BDAY[3];   
} NOTE;

void AddNote(NOTE * Notes, int NotesCount, NOTE * Temp)
{
    Notes = (struct NOTE *) realloc(Notes, (NotesCount + 1) * sizeof(struct NOTE));
    memcpy(Notes + NotesCount, Temp, sizeof(struct NOTE));
}

void main()
{
    int NotesCount = 0, i = 0, f = 0;
    int a;
    NOTE * BLOC_NOTE, * Temp;

    Temp = (struct NOTE *) malloc(sizeof(struct NOTE));
    BLOC_NOTE = (struct NOTE *) calloc(0, sizeof(struct NOTE));

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        ShowInputDialog(Temp);
        AddNote(BLOC_NOTE, NotesCount++, Temp);     
    }
}
```

On third element of BLOC_NOTE, program crashes at

```
Notes = (struct NOTE *) realloc(Notes, (NotesCount + 1) * sizeof(struct NOTE));
```

VS says me that OS Windows initiated a breakpoint...

Whats wrong?

**Edit**
Moving the code here from the comment

```
void ShowInputDialog(NOTE * Temp) 
{ 
    printf("Name: "); 
    scanf("%s", (*Temp).NAME); 
    printf("Telephone: "); 
    scanf("%s", (*Temp).TELE); 
    printf("Birthday: "); 
    scanf("%d\.%d\.\%d", (*Temp).BDAY, ((*Temp).BDAY + 1), ((*Temp).BDAY + 2));
 }
```

Comment: That looks ok, so the error must be somewhere else, like in `ShowInputDialog`. What does that do?

Comment: `void ShowInputDialog(NOTE * Temp)
{
 printf("Name: ");
 scanf("%s", (*Temp).NAME);
 printf("Telephone: ");
 scanf("%s", (*Temp).TELE);
 printf("Birthday: ");
 scanf("%d\.%d\.\%d", (*Temp).BDAY, ((*Temp).BDAY + 1), ((*Temp).BDAY + 2));
}`

Comment: I'm not sure I can decipher your format string for the date. What exactly is it supposed to mean? And what happens if the input isn't exactly as expected?

Comment: My compiler complains on \. as well! It should probably be "%d/%d/%d" or "%d.%d.%d" depending on how you write dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
void AddNote(NOTE * Notes, int NotesCount, NOTE * Temp)
{
    Notes = (struct NOTE *) realloc(Notes, (NotesCount + 1) * sizeof(struct NOTE));
    memcpy(Notes + NotesCount, Temp, sizeof(struct NOTE));
}
```

Notes is local variable that holds the address of your first `NOTE` object. But when the function returns, that value is lost. You have to return the new value, since C does not have references:

```
NOTE* AddNote(NOTE * Notes, int NotesCount, NOTE * Temp)
{
    Notes = (struct NOTE *) realloc(Notes, (NotesCount + 1) * sizeof(struct NOTE));
    memcpy(Notes + NotesCount, Temp, sizeof(struct NOTE));
    return Notes;
}

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   ShowInputDialog(Temp);
   BLOC_NOTE = AddNote(BLOC_NOTE, NotesCount++, Temp);     
}
```

In C++ this would have been enough:

```
void AddNote(NOTE * &Notes, int NotesCount, NOTE * Temp)
{
    Notes = (struct NOTE *) realloc(Notes, (NotesCount + 1) * sizeof(struct NOTE));
    memcpy(Notes + NotesCount, Temp, sizeof(struct NOTE));
}
```

Comment: An alternative fix is to pass a `NOTE**` to `AddNote()` (and adjust the use accordingly).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now I have figured it out.

```
void AddNote(NOTE * Notes, int NotesCount, NOTE * Temp)
{
    Notes = (struct NOTE *) realloc(Notes, (NotesCount + 1) * sizeof(struct NOTE));
    memcpy(Notes + NotesCount, Temp, sizeof(struct NOTE));
}
```

In `AddNote` the parameter `Notes` is a copy of `BLOC_NOTE`. If realloc succeeds in expanding the block, that is ok. However, if realloc allocates a new block (and copies everything there), `BLOC_NOTE` is suddenly invalid because it now points to freed memory.

The next time you call AddNode the memory debugger obviously detects that.

Answer (score 0):

You are ***required*** to check the pointer values returned from malloc( ), calloc( ), and realloc( ). Where have you done those checks?

Comment: I can print those values after input. With them everything is in order.. But program crashes at 3rd realloc...(or VS)